# Does cv2.flip return a BGR or an RGB image?

Tags: opencv, python

Does cv2.flip return a BGR image? or it will return the same type as the source image (either RGB, or BGR)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.flip()` flips within each layer, leaving the ordering of the layers unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dave W. Smith.Is there any way I can check if an image is RGB or BGR?

Comment: When you use cv2 to read an image, it stores the channels internally in the order B, G, R. When you use cv2 to write that, it'll land in the correct order for tools that expect RGB. One time you might need to care about orders if you're trying to display an image that you read from cv2 in a Jupyter notebook. Then, `cv2.cvtImage(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` will hand you back an in-memory representation that displays correctly.